# Odoo: Price List - How to archive through API

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm new to Odoo and I'm building a python backend which should create products and price lists in Odoo through API calls. Everything went fairly easy until I tried programatically setting a Price List as archived.

From my research I found that the archive setting is directly linked to the 'Active' property of the Price List. Unfortunately, my code isn't working, and the Price List is still active and unarchived.

```
price_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.pricelist', 'create', [{

'name': "Test List", 

'currency_id': "1",

    'active':'False'

}])
```

**UPDATED**

I cannot seem to archive a product. The active property is updated to False, but the product still appears in the product list and not in the archived product list.

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.product', 'write', [[prod_id], {
    'name': "Testing Apple MacBook 111", 'active':False, 'is_product_variant':False
}])
```

Comment: You're using a string as value for `active`, but it should be a boolean: `'active': False`. A non empty string is True, so you won't deactivate the pricelist. (`boolean('False') == True`)

Comment: Thank you! I've update my question. Do you have any ideea why product archiving doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You have called `create` method means every time you run API, it will create a new pricelist. - Use `write` method.
2. 'active': False - see comment by @CZoellner

Comment: Thanks for your help! But whatever I do I cannot archive a product. The active property is updated to False but the product doesn't appear inside the archived list of products. I've updated my question.